# Test server with many requests

Tags: software-testing, http, debugging

I wrote a server which I test at the moment using `curl`. However, I can only send so many requests manually at the same time. I could `bash` something together which sends the requests for me, but I'm really looking for something very configurable. My `bash` isn't good enough for something like that.

- Preferably runs on Linux

  - Windows is acceptable, not preferred
- Should be able to send HTTP and HTTPS requests
- Should be able to send many (20+) requests with different flags/destinations after each other

  - Being able to send multiple requests at once (multi-threaded) is a pre.
- Print results either to screen or to log
- Errors should be logged
- Time-out to prevent one request from hanging the entire run

Example usage of `curl`:

```
curl -v -L -G -d "ID=2&Direction=45&Speed=8" http://10.0.0.7:4800/target/subtarget
```

Flags, query, IP, port and pathname (all behind the port) should be configurable. Preferably with ranges where reasonable.